# How to run a dockerized dnsmasq name server within a tinc VPN with only one process per container

Tags: docker, dnsmasq, tinc

I have a tinc VPN mesh network that is used by various types of hosts all over the world and I want to deploy a dockerized dnsmasq name server for use within that tinc mesh.

I have already successfully built and configured a "fat" multi-process docker container (using runit) which does what I am looking for. It runs both a tinc process and a dnsmasq process and dnsmasq is configured to bind to the tinc network interface in the container. But now I am trying to build the same functionality using 1-process containers.

I know how to build and configure a basic 1-process dnsmasq container and I know how to build and configure a basic 1-process tinc container. I can write a simple docker-compose file that will bring them both up.

What I don't know how to do is something like using the tinc container as a gateway that exposes the dnsmasq container to the mesh network, allowing other hosts on that tinc network to run DNS queries against dnsmasq. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some intense googling and adapting similar use-cases with openVPN, I figured out a working setup. Conceptually, you bind the network of the dnsmasq container to the tinc container. Here's an abbreviated docker-compose.yml that shows the essentials:

```
version: '3'
services:

  tinc:
    ...

  dnsmasq:
    depends_on: 
      - tinc
    network_mode: "service:tinc"
```

If you `docker exec -ti dnsmasq /bin/sh` after bringing this up and then do an `ifconfig` inside the dnsmasq container, you will see the tinc network interface that the tinc container creates. So if your dnsmasq config binds to that network interface, it just works.

Cool.

Comment: What about routing from tinc clients to dnsmasq? I am struggling with similar seyup using openvpn

Comment: If I understand what you are asking, then I don't know how to do that with openvpn which I don't use but understand as more of a point to point protocol. Tinc creates a mesh network like a virtual LAN so as soon as you have put the dnsmasq host on the tinc network, it is immediately available to every other host on that tinc mesh network. IOW, tinc routes for you; that's why I use it rather than something like openvpn.